# Rails find not returning a record that exists in the database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

This is a weird thing I've been encountering and I was wondering if people could give me a few pointers on where to look for problems.

What I'm doing is running a find for an id on a model. When I run it on a certain set of records, they return that record, as expected. But there's another 100 records or so, that I can see in the database (mysql), but running a find command returns an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception.

If I create another record directly in the database, I cannot pull up that record either. However, if I do a new command in the rails console, that record is retrievable. If I do a find_by_sql command, the records are retrievable.

I've tried optimizing the table, but beyond that, I'm kind of stumped as to what would be causing this. I'm running Rails 2.3.12 with Ruby 1.8.7 and the mysql gem on my local machine. Any thoughts on possible causes would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit** Thanks for the pointers - attached a logger to my console instance, which exposed the problem - a forgotten default_scope which was restricting what was returned.

Comment: Check your console log and the SQL statement generated.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - found the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something in your model that restraint the scope of your SQL queries.

Check the log for SQL produced by your Ruby code and you will find useful hints on what's going wrong.